# How to get fewer digit milliseconds

Tags: javascript

I found this example in w3schools but it returns 3 digit milliseconds, how can I get 2digit milliseconds?

I want to use chronometer in my app but don't want 3 digits.

```
function myFunction() {
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMilliseconds();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

I added Jsfiddle and I want that last number only two digits not 3.

https://jsfiddle.net/8L167jyL/3/

Comment: Milliseconds is 1sec / 1000. So you want hundredths of a second, which would be 1sec / 100? How do you think you could get that? I can think of a few ways.

Comment: What do you mean by 2 digit milliseconds? This function gives you how many milliseconds into the current second you are, i.e. from 0 to 999.

Comment: So your question is about formatting a number to a given format?

Comment: True 2 digit milliseconds: `0E2`, `1E2`, ... - please consider using the correct unit prefix, e. g. `centi`

Comment: If you don't care about rounding, then `('00' + +d).slice(-3,-1)` will do. If you want rounding, then `('0' + Math.round(d/10)).slice(-2)`;

Comment: where to put in my fiddle?

Comment: The word you're looking for is centiseconds. A millisecond is 0.001 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = d.getMilliseconds().toString().substr(0, 2)
```

Comment: This produces an incorrect result if `d.getMilliseconds()` returns a number between 1 and 99.

Comment: @MichaelLiu—Or even 0 - 99 inclusive. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 10

```js
function myFunction() {
var d = new Date();
var n = Math.round(d.getMilliseconds()/10);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: Correct as long as OP equates "two-digit milliseconds" with centisecond...

Comment: `( '0' + Math.round(d.getMilliseconds()/10)).slice(-2)` ;-)